# Error: Unable to access jarfile /snap/vue/1/jar/vue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar when creating vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, java-8, jar, runtime-error

I  used  below command to create new vue.js project.

```
sudo vue create my-app
```

but it gives following error

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
Error: Unable to access jarfile /snap/vue/1/jar/vue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

how i solve this error  to create new vue.js project?

My operating system is 'Ubuntu'

Comment: Firstly, do you have (vue-cli) installed? Check if you have it by running `vue --version` If not make sure to install it globally.
Secondly, try running the command without the sudo `vue create my-app` .

Comment: when i running 'vue --version' it gave same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I did not grant administrator privileges for installation.Therefore, I just have to give Administrator Privilege to the installation by typing `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`. Then when I need to create Vue Project I just type `sudo vue create <project_name>` then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

1. Remove the vue using snap
   `sudo snap remove vue`
2. Then install vue globally
   `npm install -g @vue/cli`